# MYsql inserting multiple entries into a column using command line

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: SQL table]

I currently have an SQL table containing information about staff members I have added a new column called `Phone_no` which set all the entries to NULL. I now need to add a phone number for each entry with the number `07072000001..25` so the first entry would be `07072000001` and the second would be `07072000002` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do use variables:

```
set @rn :=  0;

update t
    set phone_num = lpad(7072000000 + (@rn := @rn + 1), 11, '0');
```

I'm not sure if there is a particular ordering you have in mind.  If so, you can add `order by` to the `update`.